# What is the easiest way to level Light Armor with all the DLC?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Ok, so I am looking for ways that aren't time consuming (within reason), and not too terribly tedious. I have all the DLC, and I am willing to spend 3-4 hours, give or take. Thank you!

Comment: While the question ask about an archer, it lists the only ways to level light armor in the game, a trainer (of which there are three) or find a low level mob to smack you around.

Comment: My recommendation would be to put on the best light armor pieces you own.  Improve it as much as you can at a blacksmith for extra armor (potions can also add to smithing).  Enchant the armor with as much +healing rate as possible (again, potions can add to enchanting).  For any pieces where healing rate isn't an option, try to add +magicka, +health, or +light armor.  Stand in front of a giant and take as much damage as you can.  If your total armor is still too light due to low-level smithing, consider starting off with a smaller enemy.  Use healing spells to stay alive. Run away if needed.